# Retrieve a specific setting from jQuery.ajaxSetup()

Tags: jquery, ajax, asynchronous, synchronization

I have page that possibly calls this line.

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({async:false})
```

In another function I would like to know what state in what state this async flag is at.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct thing would probably be to have your page set a flag if it calls `ajaxSetup`, so you know.

You can hack jQuery instead, though, and use the undocumented `jQuery.ajaxSettings` object:

```
if (!jQuery.ajaxSettings.async) {
    // ...
}
```

As with using anything undocumented, you run the risk of this breaking from one dot release to the next (1.6.0 to 1.6.1, for instance). jQuery's had `jQuery.ajaxSettings` since version 1.1, but that doesn't mean they won't shake things up.

You can also put in a feature request [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/report) (after searching to make sure it hasn't already been requested).

Comment: Great it works well, I thought about using my own flag but I writing for a little library of my own so using ajaxSettings makes good sense.

Comment: I will investigate making it a feature. Again thanks for the quick and clear response! SO rocks...